# How to select inner divs with the IDs?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to select a div within a div by specifying the ID.

HTML with specified ID

```
<div id="divOuter">
   <div id="divInner">
   </div>
</div>
```

And if I want to select divInner by using ID selectors in more to the point style what should I use?

I tried

```
div#divOuter> div#divInner
```

but cannot make it work.

Comment: Why not just `#divInner` ? There should only be one with that ID, right?

Comment: How can `div#divOuter > div#divInner` not work?

Comment: As an aside, "divInner" and "divOuter" are bad IDs for your elements. "inner" and "outer" are sufficient.

Comment: @BoltClock: Probably because most versions of IE don't support the child selector.

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand: Hmmm, you're right; out of 9 versions, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 don't support it.

Answer (score 4):

As IDs have to be unique,

```
#divInner
```

is sufficient.

If you have more elements with the same ID you have to change that (you might want to use classes instead).

**Update:**

Ok, I got your point. But your selector is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/AsPam/

Either you have another rule that overrides this one, or your structure is different.

**Update 2:**

Oh, as others have noted , [the child selector is not supported by IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t11). You have to omit it then:

```
div#divOuter div#divInner
```

Comment: In the same page yes, unique. But what if I have many pages which may have this ID and if I have styling in one separate style.cs? I was thinking to specify IDs in this way can reduce the risk of overriding some others.

Comment: Felix, I think div#divOuter div#divInner  does not work. I had to use div#divInner to selevt the divInner. No idea why... But good to know > childe selector is not supported in sOME IE versions.

Answer (score 1):

As IDs are unique all you really need is

```
#divInner
{
    /*styles*/
}
```

This will select the ID attribute of the HTML element and apply the styles.

If you need to repeat the styles to more than one element, use a class

```
.divInner
{
    /*styles*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#divOuter div{...}
```

or

```
#divInner{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters (and I know this might be a typo), have you checked the spelling?

When it comes to the selection, you seem to want to use the `id` tag, in other words, all you need is to do as everyone above says: `#idInner{...}`